# I want to Install Laragon in my Bootcamp of Windows in my mac

Tags: mysql, netbeans, mysql-connector, laragon

I have Windows 10 in my MAC and i'm using the default bootcamp of it, I'm also using apache for my class and know we have to use Laragon and install Laragon, but I have this problem when I press start all, i put a picture of it,.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o56CU.png)

Anyone knows what can I do for fix this problem or there is not change to do this with my disk partition.

I tried to do as admin but it doesn't work

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain anything - e.g. steps to reproduce, log output etc - in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also, I've removed the [tag:apache] tag, as you might have Apache httpd involved, but the problem is unrelated. Please check this for the other tags as well. However, without logs or other information, there's no way to help.

Comment: Is this a MySQL problem or a Netbeans problem?